# Add delay before DragItemsStarting C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

How can i add delay before DragItemsStarting event in C#? This event is defined in xaml. So, how can i control it in xaml.cs file, or anyother way?

Here's the code:

xaml:

```
<GridView DragItemsStarting="NoteBaseListView_DragItemsStarting">

</GridView>
```

code behind: xaml.cs:

```
private void NoteBaseListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{       
}
```

Comment: Registering Events should be done in the Load method which is performed after the Initialization (constructor code) so objects get defined before events get registers.  Some Event you have to make sure object is fully initialized.  So like a DataGridView the row count is set to -1 initially.  Then after columns are added the row count is set to zero.  So normally a DGV you test in events that Row Count >= 0.

Comment: Could you share the code about this delay event ?

Comment: Updated the post, i want to add delay before this event fires. Want to delay the drag.

Comment: Do you mean that you want call some method in the `NoteBaseListView_DragItemsStarting` delay?

Comment: i want to add delay before NoteBaseListView_DragItemsStarting triggers. If i do delay inside of that function, it won't delay. i want to delay before dragging occurs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the user to hold the list item for longer before he can drag it?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes, exactly that.

Comment: You could simply use a ListView instead of a GridView. List Items already require the user to "hold" on the item before it becomes draggable.

Comment: @AdamMcMahon Grid view is a requirement.

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman, You could add the `PointerPressed` event for GridViewItem, it will be called before drag starting.